# Alternate html and text plain - avoid short messages like "your mailreader don't support html message"

Tags: mutt, html-mail

I would like to read multpart (html and alternative text together) text/plain
first.

So, I set muttrc as follow:

```
.mutt/muttrc
auto_view text/html
alternative_order text/plain text/html
```

and mailcap as:

```
.mutt/mailcap
text/html; lynx -force_html -assume_charset=gbk -assume_local_charset=gbk /
 -assume_unrec_charset=gbk -display_charset=utf8 -dump -force_html '%s'; /
 description="HTML Text"; nametemplate=%s.html; copiousoutput
```

This is ok and mutt read text plain first when message have only text plain or both, html end text plain.

However, some messages have html and a single and sort alternate text plain
said "your mailreader don't support html message". in this case, I need to hint "v" and select alternate html and hint enter to read the message.

If I change muttrc to:

Comment: Change it to what?

Comment: “If I change muttrc to:” What?

Answer (score 0):

For this case you can use message-hooks - just add them to your config file.

From neomutt manual:

> message-hook   pattern   command
>
> Before NeoMutt displays (or formats for replying or forwarding) a message which matches the given pattern (or, when it is preceded by an exclamation mark, does not match the pattern ), the given command is executed. When multiple message-hook s match, they are executed in the order in which they occur in the configuration file.

See example below:

```
message-hook 'PATTERN' "unalternative_order *; alternative_order text/html text/plain"
```

That would change alternative order to text/html for matching pattern. Pattern can be anything described in Pattern modifiers section of the manual. See
[mutt manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#tab-patterns) or [neomutt manual](https://neomutt.org/guide/advancedusage#3-1-%C2%A0pattern-modifier).

To test if your pattern works as expected try  in running instance of neomutt in a mailbox containing the tested message.
For example:
`l<enter>~s Mysubject<enter>`should limit the mailbox to display just e-mails matching subject **Mysubject**

Answer (score 0):

In neomutt this can be done with the [show_multipart_alternative](https://neomutt.org/guide/reference.html#3-404-%C2%A0show_multipart_alternative) setting:

```
auto_view text/plain text/utf-8 text/html
alternative_order text/plain text/html
set show_multipart_alternative=inline
```